# SharePoint Linked List issue with MS Access

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint

I have set up SharePoint List of over 100,000 items (dummy data). This list will be updated one row at a time by users, no problems on thorough testing of this. On linking to this List in Access 2016 and running any query I am getting the message 'System.OutOfMemoryException'. This did not happen yesterday when I was building and testing the database but started today which is confusing me. I've tried it throughout the day and getting the same message. The individual updates continue to work fine.
Any help would be appreciated as without the query function the project is dead in the water.
Thanks
Nat

Comment: Have I been 'throttled'?

Answer (score 0):

I don't suggest going beyond about 10,000 rows for SharePoint lists and Access. I have pushed a table/list to 80,000 rows. However, that was on a local network, and I had to setup (remove) the SharePoint "default" limitations (so, limits of 50 columns, and the 5,000 row limit "governor" all have to be set/removed). If you are using cloud based 365 hosting you CAN NOT change these settings or limits. And thus default list sizes are set at 5,000 rows. (you can grow beyond 5,000 rows, but the FIRST upload of that list (say from Access) MUST be less then 5,000 rows, else the system will not allow you to index the list. (and without indexing, then things run even slower).

So, it depends on your SharePoint hosting. But a linked access table to SharePoint really should not go much beyond 5,000 rows (if 365 cloud based). If the lists are larger, then the application(s) types that will work are those that DO NOT update large numbers of rows. The reason for this issue is that while Access has a VERY great "local" cache of the data, and even allows you to update rows when you are off line? Well, any update of rows has to occur local, then then on SharePoint side. It is in effect a "sync" system, and thus you cannot execute a server side sql (or recordset) update. The update's have to occur on both sides, and thus updates to LARGE datasets are VERY VERY slow.

For a table of 100,000 rows? You need to use sql server. A SharePoint list is going to be trouble once you pass about 15,000 rows. If the SharePoint server is 100% local on your network, then you can configure (remove) all the throttle limits, and you might get to 50,000 rows. As noted, on a local network and local hosted SharePoint, I pushed one list to 80,000 rows. But such large row counts are still pushing things, and I doubt the end result will be a great user experience.

While SharePoint lists can be huge, such designs then ONLY work well if you pull say one record (or document, or whatever), update it, and then it is saved. Using a "list" as some large table like "sql" database simply as noted does not work well. The main issue/reason is you can't execute the SQL updates on the server side. So, you might be able to query the data - SharePoint can do that quite well.

but large udpates to many rows out of a list? No that simply does not work well nor follow the SharePoint model and how SharePoint works.

All list updates occur client side - one by one, and row by row. And thus Access will/has to shuffle each update from client to server via a sync model. Such updates are going to be turtle slow. There is simply NO MEANS to run a large row update 100% server side. And if you did put some code sharepoint side? Well, each row now has to be synced against the local copy of the list that Access has. So, even if the update of many rows was fast, Access will NOW then attempt to sync against that large number of updates - and that is again slow as turtles.  (so, even a 100% server side update is slow, since each and every row now has to be pulled down and update + synced against the local table). In sql server, there is no local table copy - so a udpate to 10 rows, or 100,000 rows will occur in an instant, since no data has to be synced back down to Access.

I don't think the out of memory error is your problem. You might be able to fix that issue, but the resulting update speeds are going to be oh so slow that the over all experience and usability will not meet basic standards for a application to interact with such data.

You don't have the correct and viable architecture for such large updates.

Comment: Thanks for this Albert. Much appreciated. This pretty much answers my question. I read that the upper threshold of items in a list can be up to 30 million,which I thought would be fine for adding an item at a time from multiple users. I was hoping to have a list of up to 1 million items. Is this step of the process not still viable? And then run select queries from this list, no bulk updates. Nat

Comment: No, not a good idea. Support of huge lists is well known in SharePoint. But thinking of those lists as a large database table don't work well. Pulling one row from very large lists works well. But using such large lists as a database system is a different use case. In some cases, you might re-design your software to say not update large numbers of rows. So, often you might have some process that empties out a table, copies a bunch of records to that table, and then do extensive data processing on that temp data. Such designs and data processing approaches don't work well for SharePoint lists.